# ¿Cómo puedo crear sesiones de usuario en Symfony 2.7.3?

Tags: php, symfony2

Estoy creando un sistema, pero quiero implementar inicio de sesiones. ¿Me podrían dar a conocer alguna información que me pueda servir?

Comment: ¿Quieres un sistema de sesiones o quieres autenticar usuarios? Symfony incorporta un componente llamado Security con el que puedes hacer esto último en 4 o 5 sencillos pasos.

Answer (score 1):

Para implementar sesiones, primero debes NO tener sesiones nativas de php en tu programa ($_SESSION). para comenzar a usar, debes darle `use` a la siguiente librería

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

Para iniciar la session (típicamente en el controlador del Login para un logeo exitoso)

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();
```

luego, Para el get/set de variables usar, por ejemplo

```
$session->set('name', 'h40s4m4');
$session->get('name');
```

Para tu versión de Symfony, te recomiendo leer este artículo de la documentación

http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Como dice h40sm4m4 en ese link hay info y también [aquí](http://librosweb.es/libro/symfony_2_x/capitulo_5/gestionando_la_sesion.html)

de hecho donde asigna:

```
$session->set('name','h40s4m4');
```

tu puedes enviar todo el usuario como objeto o arreglo
suponiendo que tu usuario viene de un

```
$usuario = select * from usuario where id="x"// que con symfony debería ser con doctrine, tu puedes decir:


$session->set('usuario',$usuario);
```

y lo obtienes igual

```
$user = $session->get('usuario'); ya solo navegas en sus propiedades o índices, si es arreglo
```